# Google.UserMessagingPlatform to setup GRDP Admod in Dotnet Maui mobile app

Tags: maui

I need set up Google.UserMessagingPlatform to setup GRDP Admod for my Dotnet Maui mobile app. Anyone have done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the nugget package [Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform/#usedby-body-tab) into your MAUI app to use Google User Messaging Platform to setup GRDP Admod.

Here's the source repo:https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/ for the SDK, you can report to it if you have any questions or issues.